# How do I use reduce to count up totals and modify my array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, group-by, reduce

I use Redux to store all my products in a list. Displayed thist list looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "BLACK TEA",
    "supplieruuid": "SLIGRO",
    "price": 1.10,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "GREEN TEA",
    "supplieruuid": "SLIGRO",
    "price": 1.10,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "PURPLE TEA",
    "supplieruuid": "BUNZL",
    "price": 1.10,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "RAINBOW TEA",
    "supplieruuid": "BUNZL",
    "price": 1.10,
  },
]
```

I'm using this reduce function to group these products together by key **supplieruuid**.

```
    const sortedBySupplierUUID = state.entities.cart.list.reduce(
    (hash, { ["supplieruuid"]: value, ...rest }) => ({ ...hash, [value]: (hash[value] || []).concat({ ["supplieruuid"]: value, ...rest }) }),
    {}
  );
  return Object.keys(sortedBySupplierUUID).map((key) => ({ title: key, data: sortedBySupplierUUID[key] }));
```

What this returns is as following:

```
 [
    {
        title: "SLIGRO",
        data: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "BLACK TEA",
            "price": 1.10,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "GREEN TEA",
            "price": 1.10,
        },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: "BUNZL",
        data: [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "PURPLE TEA",
            "price": 1.10,
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "RAINBOW TEA",
            "price": 1.10,
        },
        ],
    },
]
```

This all works fine, except for that I a **total** added to the object which will count up the total price of the items in the "data" array of each object as following:

```
[
        {
            title: "SLIGRO",
            total: 2.20,
            data: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "BLACK TEA",
                "price": 1.10,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "GREEN TEA",
                "price": 1.10,
            },

            ],
        },
        {
            title: "BUNZL",
            total: 2.20,
            data: [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "PURPLE TEA",
                "price": 1.10,
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "RAINBOW TEA",
                "price": 1.10,
            },
            ],
        },
    ]
```

How can I achieve this by modifying the reduce function I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const selectSortedItems = (state) => {
  const sortedBySupplierUUID = state.entities.cart.list.reduce((hash, { ["supplieruuid"]: value, ...rest }) => ({ ...hash, [value]: (hash[value] || []).concat({ ...rest }) }), {});
  return Object.keys(selectSortedItems(sortedBySupplierUUID)).map(key => (
         { 
             title: key, 
             total: sortedBySupplierUUID[key].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.price),
             data: sortedBySupplierUUID[key] 
         })
  )};
}
```

More intuitive way of doing it

```
const selectSortedItems = (state) => {
    const itemsMap = {};

    state.entities.cart.list.map((item) => {
        if (itemsMap[item.supplieruuid]) {
            itemsMap[item.supplieruuid].total += item.price;
            itemsMap[item.supplieruuid].data.push(item);
        } else {
            itemsMap[item.supplieruuid] = {
                title: item.supplieruuid,
                total: item.price,
                data: [item]
            }
        }
    });

    return Object.values(itemsMap);
}
```

Comment: Dear Souvik, thank you for your response. Your second solution seemed to do it for me, thank you for your help! @Souvik Nandi